# How to get currently entering text from UITextField Delegate?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have used this delegate method but it's not returning last character which I entered.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
```

Eg. Current Text field string is "123" and when I enter "4", so textfield string is "1234" but above delegate method return only "123", now again entered "5" then above method return "1234" but I'm expecting "12345"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But later I found the solution which works for me

**Swift 5**

```
 func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        
        var finalString = ""
        if range.length > 0 {
            finalString = "\(textField.text!.dropLast())"
        } else {
            finalString = "\(textField.text! + string)"
        }
        print(finalString)
        return true
    }
```

Comment: You know you can remove more than 1 char? so length could be 10 and you remove just 1.